# Alter table adding unique constraint with no check SSDT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a SSDT project and we publish databases via dacpac/sqlpackage.
Now I have a existing table with duplicate records.
And I am adding a UNIQUE constraint so that the records should not be duplicated.
This is how my table script looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE [AM].[WorkflowStep]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [StepName] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    [IsAutomated] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [TenantId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    *CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_STEP] UNIQUE (StepName, IsAutomated, TenantId)*
)
```

**The constraint is newly added**. I was expecting the `sqlpackage.exe` to generate publish script with constraint added with `NOCHECK` Option and then finally altered with `CHECK` option. But that is not happening. The script has only an alter table option.

```
ALTER TABLE [WorkflowStep]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_STEP] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([StepName] ASC, [IsAutomated] ASC, [TenantId] ASC);
```

Can someone throw light on why it is so? Is this specific to `UNIQUE` constraints. I have other constraints in other tables for which the sqlpackage adds constraints with `NOCHECK` option initially but they are foreign key references.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily test this yourself:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t(ID int); 
INSERT #t(ID) VALUES (1), (1); 
ALTER TABLE #t WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_#t_ID UNIQUE(ID);
```

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.#t...' and the index name 'UQ_#t_ID'. The duplicate key value is (1).

This proves that `NOCHECK` is ignored. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) also specify an effect only for `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints, though they do not say what the behavior is for other constraints.

There is a good technical reason why it works this way: a `UNIQUE` constraint must be backed by an index, and the physical structure of a `UNIQUE` index differs from a non-`UNIQUE` index. Specifically, a non-`UNIQUE` index has a uniquifier, an invisible, nullable integer column added to indexed rows to make them unique anyway and allow the engine to identify individual rows. To allow creating a unique constraint `WITH NOCHECK` and then later applying `WITH CHECK` would actually require rebuilding the index, at the very least changing the metadata -- this is no better than just creating the index correctly from the start as either `UNIQUE` or non-`UNIQUE`, depending on what you need. By contrast, a `FOREIGN KEY`/`CHECK` constraint can always be verified later without having to rewrite data.